# Get JSON Data from Javascript var that was created with the help of PHP DomDocument() Function

Tags: javascript, php, regex, domdocument

I'm currently working on a project to get Download Links for Vimeo Videos. As you know Vimeo the same as YouTube doesn't support the direct download feature via its rest API. Because I know that Vimeo provides the CDN Links on the resource link of their embed player at https://player.vimeo.com/video/{videoId} I've create a simple DomDocument Function to access the specific JavaScript that holds the required download links. Here is my Code:

```
// Define the Vimeo ID
$vimeoVideoId = htmlspecialchars((int) $_GET["id"]);

// Create new DomDocument Object.
$vimeoObject = new DOMDocument();

// Load the HTML Vimeo Embed Url
$vimeoObject->loadHTMLFile("https://player.vimeo.com/video/" . $vimeoVideoId);

// Create new XPath Dom Object
$xpathObject = new DOMXPath($vimeoObject);

// Get all JavaScript Elements without src="" attributes of the Vimeo Embed URL 
Webpage
$getJavaScript = $xpathObject->query('//body//script[not(@src)]');

// Convert DomObject to Array with the help of iterator_to_array() Function.
$createArrayFromGetJavaScript = iterator_to_array($getJavaScript);

// Get rid of the first Array Part because the relevant content is in the 
second Array Part
$array_shift = array_shift($createArrayFromGetJavaScript);

// Output the JavaScript Content with Vimeo CDN Video Files
echo $createArrayFromGetJavaScript[0]->nodeValue;
```

When you now take a closer look to the generated output you can see that all required infos are wrapped inside valid JSON and this valid JSON is the value of variable r.

[Valid JSON inside r variable - Screenshot on what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvJS9.png)

Now my question. The code above is running as it should but how can I get access to the content of this specific variable? Because when I can get the entire JSON element I can iterate through it via `json_decode($json, true);`in PHP. Is there a way to do it. I thought about something like `regex` with `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`. But I don't know how to create this regex string or how to output the matched content yet. A good resource for beginners would also help, because then I can also learn something for future projects. I've already researched at this German website here: https://www.php-einfach.de/php-tutorial/regulaere-ausdruecke/ But here I can only find if statements that say okay the thing that you are looking for is in your string but there is no example on how to download it. I've tried it with echo preg_match(...); But that only outputs 1. So it would be really great if you can help me a bit with this problem.

Thx in advance.
Paul

**Update**

I`ve tried this code here but now it outputs nothing:

```
<?
header("Content-type: text/plain");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Define the Vimeo ID
$vimeoVideoId = htmlspecialchars((int) $_GET["id"]);

// Create new DomDocument Object.
$vimeoObject = new DOMDocument();

// Load the HTML Vimeo Embed Url
$vimeoObject->loadHTMLFile("https://player.vimeo.com/video/" . $vimeoVideoId);

// Create new XPath Dom Object
$xpathObject = new DOMXPath($vimeoObject);

// Get all JavaScript Elements without src="" attributes of the Vimeo Embed URL Webpage
$getJavaScript = $xpathObject->query('//body//script[not(@src)]');

// Convert DomObject to Array with the help of iterator_to_array() Function.
$createArrayFromGetJavaScript = iterator_to_array($getJavaScript);

// Get rid of the first Array Part because the relevant content is in the second Array Part
$array_shift = array_shift($createArrayFromGetJavaScript);

preg_match("/var r = ({.+})/", $createArrayFromGetJavaScript[0]->nodeValue, $extracted_json);
// $extracted_json now contains the json as a string.
$json = json_decode($extracted_json[1], true);
// $json now contains the json parsed as an object.
print_r($json);
?>
```

Instead it shows the following errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : iframe in 
https://player.vimeo.com/video/287117046, line: 1 in index.php on line 12

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Unexpected end tag : div in 
https://player.vimeo.com/video/287117046, line: 1 in index.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in index.php on line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comments to this answer, I now understand that you wish to extract the json data.

**Step 1: Construct the regex to extract the json data.**
Since you mentioned the json is stored in the `r` variable, and given the fact that json starts with a `{`-bracket and ends with a `}`-bracket, we can use the following regex to capture everything in between, since we know that regular expressions match the first longest match.

`var r=({.+})`

**Step 2: Capture the matches using PHP.**

We can use the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function for this.

```
<?php
$inputstring = 'function() var r = {"cdn_url": ..", "request": {"files": {"dash": { "id": 654654654, "fps": 23}}}}';
preg_match("/var r=({.+})/", $inputstring, $extracted_json);
// $extracted_json now contains the json as a string.
$json = json_decode($extracted_json[1]);
// $json now contains the json parsed as an object.
?>
```

**Useful links:**

- https://www.phpliveregex.com/
- https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The above Links are very useful. They'll help me when making some regex experiments. :-) Now to your answer. I might have been not precisely enough to say what I mean. I have this output here: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/24w3. I need a solution to get the value inside the first var {r} because it is valid JSON and I can simply parse it via json_decode(); My current regex is like this: (var r = {|}$) Is it possible to get the content of the JavaScript var {r}? I don't know if it's a correct start or not. I've also tested your code but it outputs nothing.

Comment: That's possible yes, I will update my answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much @thepieterdc

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. But I think the problem is a little bit more complex. Here is my JSFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/u7d14bat/ That is the exact Code that was outputted by my function mentioned above. But when I've tested your code it also outputs a little bit JavaScript with the JSON and when I test it with my full JavaScript Input it generates the error shown here: https://3v4l.org/1OmAl (Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ...) I actually don't know how to solve this, because when I try to output print_r($extracted_json) it is an empty array.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that in my JavaScript Input there are also multiple closing } in the code. Maybe that's the case why your function includes them also. I've also seen that var = r is still available in the $extracted_json variable. Mh pretty complex. Hope we can solve this problem, because there are currently not much vimeo php downloder alternatives on the web.

Comment: The problem lies with the newlines, this for example works: https://3v4l.org/C5eov

Comment: I've updated my question. Now it outputs errors and shows nothing. Maybe you can take a look on it, because I actually don't know how to get the download links from the JSON with a different approach.